# what is error cannot find WebServlet class?

Tags: java

I am using 12c web server. I make a .java file and compile it using jdk6_29 which is present in 12c. In java file I use annotation @WebServlet but when i compile it, it give errors class WebServlet not find...please tell me what is problem.

Comment: Post your Servlet Code

Comment: Did you `import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet`?

Comment: yes I have imported it

Comment: add exact stack trace here .